# set initial graphs on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

believe me when i say, I have looked for a solution for this simple problem in here and online in general.

i have installed an highchart solution on my site. 
The users in highcharts can show/hide graphs dynamically afer the chart has loaded.
I want to load, let's say, 3 sets of graph data but to hide (the user can show afterwards if he wants) 1 of them.

so I want to load the 3 graphs but to display only 2 of them.

```
 chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({ chart: {renderTo: "graphDiv2", zoomType: "xy"
```

Comment: Do you want to hide a chart or do you want to hide a series? If it is a chart you have several jQuery options and if it is a series you can do it inside of highcharts itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to display your 3 charts and hide theire div content. Then when user want's to see the second chart for example, you show the div which it's placed.
You can do it using **[jQuery.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)** and **[jQuery.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)**.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to hide series add this to your chart

```
 legend: {
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 150 ,
      },
```

if you are trying to hide the chart it self AS richardo said add a hide() / show() button to your code